# How to connect a Python server and Python client each in their pod on Kubernetes?

Tags: python, kubernetes, kubernetes-pod, kubernetes-service

I have 2 pods (server, client) and a service (TCP, ClusterIP and port) within the same node. I wish to connect the 2 pods using the port given by the service (right now i hardcoded it).

The server works at least with `0.0.0.0` as IP but the client won't work with seemingly anything. What am I doing wrong? I have tried to use things like `os.getenv('SERVER_ADDRESS')` and `int(os.getenv('SERVER_PORT'))` but they both have returned `None`.

```py
import socket


def start_server():
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    
    s.bind(("0.0.0.0", 6666))
    s.listen(1)
    c, a = s.accept()
    filetodown = open("output_received.txt", "wb")
    while True:
       print("Receiving....")
       data = c.recv(1024)
       if not data:
           print("Done Receiving.")
           break
       filetodown.write(data)
       filetodown.flush()
       print(type(filetodown))

    filetodown.close()
    s.close()
    #...
```

client:

```py
import socket


def send_transaction_file():
    file_to_send = open('output.txt', 'rb')
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

    s.connect(("0.0.0.0", 6666))
    data = file_to_send.read(1024)

    while data:
        print("Sending...")
        print(str(data))
        s.send(data)
        data = file_to_send.read(1024)

    file_to_send.close()
    print("Done")
    s.shutdown(2)
    s.close()
```

EDIT: the definition of the pods:

```py
import time

from kubernetes import config, client
from kubernetes.client import Configuration
from kubernetes.client.api import core_v1_api
from kubernetes.client.rest import ApiException
from kubernetes.stream import stream

def exec_commands(api_instance, podName, app_name, python_script):
    name = podName
    resp = None
    try:
        resp = api_instance.read_namespaced_pod(name=name,
                                                namespace='default')
    except ApiException as e:
        if e.status != 404:
            print("Unknown error: %s" % e)
            exit(1)

    if not resp:
        print("Pod %s does not exist. Creating it..." % name)
        pod_manifest = {
            'apiVersion': 'v1',
            'kind': 'Pod',
            'metadata': {
                'name': name,
                'labels': {
                    'app': app_name}
            },
            'spec': {
                'hostname': podName,
                'subdomain': app_name,
                'containers': [{
                    'image': 'python',
                    'name': name,
                    "args": [
                        "/bin/sh",
                        "-c",
                        "pip install kubernetes google-api-python-client google-cloud-container python-hosts && while true;do date;sleep 5; done"
                        #"python3 " + python_script
                    ]
                }]
            }
        }
        resp = api_instance.create_namespaced_pod(body=pod_manifest,
                                                  namespace='default')
        while True:
            resp = api_instance.read_namespaced_pod(name=name,
                                                    namespace='default')
            if resp.status.phase != 'Pending':
                break
            time.sleep(1)
        print("Done.")
```

EDIT2: the definition of the service:

```
def create_service(core_v1_api):
    body = kube_setup.client.V1Service(
        api_version="v1",
        kind="Service",
        metadata=kube_setup.client.V1ObjectMeta(
            name="banking-svc"
        ),

        spec=kube_setup.client.V1ServiceSpec(
            selector={"app": "banking"},
            type="ClusterIP",
            ports=[kube_setup.client.V1ServicePort(
                port=6666,
                target_port=6666,
                protocol="TCP"
            )]
        )
    )
    core_v1_api.create_namespaced_service(namespace="default", body =body)
```

Comment: `0.0.0.0` is not a routable address for the client. Please use the pod's service DNS name https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/dns-pod-service/ We also need to see your pod definitions to tell you why `os.getenv` doesn't work

Comment: If I look up the IP-address of the pod with the client and use that, e.g. `172-17-0-4.default.pod.cluster.local` I get an `ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 111] Connection refused`

Comment: Are you creating a Service to match the Pod?  Why a bare Pod and not a Deployment or another higher-level object?

Comment: Yes, I also have a service. Because I didn't know that a deployment is better.

Comment: You should not manually "lookup" any IP address. The Service DNS name like `banking-svc.default.cluster.local` is what you want.

Comment: Also worth pointing out that `exec_commands` function doesn't run any of your Python code within the created pods. It just installs some pip modules, then runs an infinite loop, which would explain why you get a connection error - there are no servers running.

Answer (score 0):

This is working fine on your local because 0.0.0.0 is directing your loop-back adress which is okay while your server and client working on the same machine.

But if you are deploying your client as an different pod, you need to expose your server pod as a service and configure your client to use that service. Best way to do it would be reading ip part of `s.connect(0.0.0.0, 6666)` line as environment variable.

After that you need to send server address as an environment variable into the client pod. The reason `int(os.getenv('SERVER_ADDRESS'))` is returning None is that you need to send SERVER_ADDRESS variable through pods yaml file.

Comment: Ok that sounds promising but how do I that? I call os.getenv on a pod... So how do I do that other than calling it on a pod?

Comment: @topkek Please see https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/define-environment-variable-container/